# How to create a maps app where can see location of friends

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

```
Android Studio 2.2 RC 2
```

I am creating am maps using `com.google.android.maps.v2` and wondering is there a way I can build this where I can see my friends locations on the map? I have seen applications like wuze where you register and can see other wuze users.

My plan create database on a server where the user can access through a restful webservice. Their location will periodically be sent to the database through the webservice using json and other users of the apps will receive this from the webservice and update their location for everyone to see.

However, a couple of problems concerning the google maps is how can I update their location using a icon to be displayed on everyones app?

If google maps doesn't have these features are they any friend party maps I can use?

Many thanks for any suggestions

Comment: You need to communicate to that server where the locations will be stored. You can always update a google map and all the pins in it.

Comment: I would also like not to use the pins but maybe custom icons to make a distinction between friends. Every friend could have their own icon for identify.

Comment: There is good documentation on custom markers for Google maps. Have you looked it up?

Answer (score 1):

[Scroll down to "Customize a marker"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker?hl=en). As you can see, there is a way to add a custom icon which could be your friend's user profile picture.